# Find closed-form Infinite summation of two Legendre polynomials's product

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, special-functions, legendre-polynomials

I want to find analytical summation formulas for these type series of Legendre polynomials:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}P_{n-1}(cos\phi)P_{n}(cos\theta)}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}P_{n+1}(cos\phi)P_{n}(cos\theta)}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2n+1}P_{n-1}(cos\phi)P_{n}(cos\theta)}$$
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{2n+1}P_{n+1}(cos\phi)P_{n}(cos\theta)}$$

I find some formulas in the page of http://functions.wolfram.com/Polynomials/LegendreP/23/02/, but no formula can be used directly, so I seek help here. Any advice and hint are appreciated! Thank you very much.

Comment: any reason to believe htat a closed form exists?

Comment: If there is no $P_{n-1}(cos\phi)$  or $P_{n+1}(cos\phi)$, we can find closed-from summation for these series. So maybe they have ***.